# Unwanted message in flexdashboard from sf

Tags: r, knitr, r-sf, flexdashboard

The use of sf::st_write(...) in my flexdashboard through:

````
```{r,message=FALSE,warning = FALSE}
st_write(SPDF_sf_2154, here("geo","pts2154_2.shp"), append=FALSE)
```
````

causes unwanted message in the html output, like:

```
    Deleting layer `pts2154_2' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Writing layer `pts2154_2' to data source 
  `/Users/tristanlorino/Nextcloud/SonoRezé/Documents de travail/Analyse-R/Sonoreze/geo/pts2154_2.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Writing 228000 features with 5 fields and geometry type Point.
```

How can I avoid it?

Thanx,
Tristan

Comment: did you tried `results='hide'`? in the chunk setup/header? Eg `{r,message=FALSE,warning = FALSE,results='hide'}`

Comment: Thank you very much ! I have written two consecutive chunks, the first one without results (but storing a map in a object), the second one to produce the map (by call to the object).